# How 'java.lang.NullPointerException:void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setElevation(float)' on a null object reference'

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

My code:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_airport_shuttle_black_24dp)
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fingerprint_black_24dp)
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp)
//remove Actionbar Shadow
ActionBar actionBar = 'getSupportActionBar'
actionBar.setElevation(0)
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setElevation(float)' on a null object reference'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change:

```
ActionBar actionBar = 'getSupportActionBar'
actionBar.setElevation(0)
```

to:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setElevation(0)
}
```